# "Two children with the same key" error when trying to populate a multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to create a multi-select dropdown using Semantic UI and React that dynamically fetches data from an API. It successfully manages to fetch the data, but when I search for the same data again, it re-adds it to the list of options and I get a "two children with the same key" console error.

I added an exclusion statement "if (!this.state.options.includes(e))" but apparently this does not help.

I also tried to loop through the currently received data and the previous state and match the ID's against each other to prevent the same values from being populated, but had no luck with this strategy either.

```
  getOptions = () => {

      if(this.state.searchQuery) {
          this.setState({isFetching:true})
          axios.get('URL', {
              params: {
                  query: this.state.searchQuery,
                  api_key: KEY
              }
          })  

          .then( (response) => {

              this.setState((prevState)=>({

                  options: [
                  ...response.data.results.map( (e) => {  

                      if (!this.state.options.includes(e)) {
                          return {

                              key: e.id,
                              text: e.name, 
                              value: e.id
                          }   
                      }

                  })
                  , ...prevState.options]

              }), () => this.setState({isFetching:false}))

          }).catch(function () {
              return
          })
      }
  }


handleChange = (e, { value }) => {this.setState({ value })}
handleSearchChange = (e, { searchQuery }) => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery }, () => {this.getOptions()}
  )}

render() {
  const { options, isFetching, search, value } = this.state

  return (
      <Grid>
          <Grid.Column width={5}>
          <Dropdown
              fluid
              onAddItem={this.handleAddition}
              selection
              multiple
              search={search}
              options={options}
              value={value}
              placeholder="Search keywords"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
              disabled={isFetching}
              loading={isFetching}
          />
          </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
      )
  }
```

I would want the options menu not to add the same search results to the options list that already are there, when I search for the same data again.

Comment: is `Dropdown` from a from an external library or is it your own component? If it is your own component can you add that code as well?

Comment: It is from Semantic UI
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#usage-remote

Comment: “Two children with the same key”, sorry just came here to say this sounds like a movie title :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated this answer because I believe the problem is your `map` as-is will either return an object with the desired information or not return anything. In the latter case the element won't be removed it'll just be undefined. Try the following, which performs the operation in two steps: filters the results down to only the unique results and then does the state-setting with just those unique values.

```
const unique = response.data.results.filter(e => {
  return !this.state.options.some(el => el.id === e.id);
});

this.setState(prevState => ({
  options: [
    ...unique.map(e => ({
      key: e.id,
      text: e.name, 
      value: e.id
    }), 
    ...prevState.options
  ]
}));
```

This may not be a super efficient way to check as you could be iterating through a lot of existing results. If you're hitting performance issues, you could think about maintaining your search results as an object or using something like `Set` to gain hashtable lookup efficiency.

Comment: That seems to have the exact same effect.

Comment: I wish I could say it helped, but still getting the exact same result. Still thanks though!